# How to make the chosen value of select list visible

Tags: javascript, html

How I can make the selected choice still visible until I re-choose another one?The list may contain more than 10 options

=====

```
    <form method="get" action="Chairman.php" >

        <select name="courses" id="courses" class="styled-select"  >
         <option value="courses"><--Courses--></option>
         <option value="PHYS220">Physics for Engineers</option>
         <option value="MATH210">Calculus II</option>
         <option value="MATH225">Linear Algebra with Applications</option>
      </select>

       <input type="submit" value="Search Instructor"  
       onClick="checkDropdown()"></input>
        <div id="error" style="color:red"></div>
```

=====
Also when I am trying to validate the select list,The error is displayed and then quickly it disappears

```
   <script>
    function checkDropdown () {

   var courses = document.getElementById('courses');
       if(courses.value==="courses") {  

    document.getElementById('error').innerHTML="PLEASE selecttt";

    return false;  
       }
         }

              </script>
```

Comment: First, don't use unescaped `<` characters in HTML. Second, you should try to cancel the submit function in the onclick handler if the choice has not been made. But I'm not sure what you mean with make the selected choice still visible. It does remain visible until you click the submit button.

Comment: I mean if I chose Calculas II for example ,I want calculas II to still appear ,not the option Courses. got what i mean?

Answer (score 2):

The select is reset and the error disappears because the form is still posted. The value that you return from the function doesn't stop the submission.

You should use the `onsubmit` event on the form instead of `onclick` on the button. Use `return` in the event code to convey the value from the function back to the event:

```
<form method="get" action="Chairman.php" onsubmit="return checkDropdown()">
```

Comment: Note that the checkDropdopwn function doesn't return values in all of its branches, so it may not have the desired effect in its current form.

Comment: @MrLister: It has. It's only when `false` is returned that the submission is stopped. When no specific value is returned, the return value is `undefined`, and that won't stop the submission.

Comment: @Guffa It didn't work at all with onsubmit="return checkDropdown()"

Comment: @AssoumZoghbi: Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/yLsv9kyh/ (i.e. the validation works, when the validation passes the form will be posted to a page that doesn't exist.)

Comment: how can the chosen one stay visible ?If I chose one of the courses ,I want it to stay

Comment: @AssoumZoghbi: If you mean after the postback, then you have to solve that in the server code that creates the page. Set the `selected` attribute on the option that should be selected.

Comment: @Guffa Are you sure that no return value has the same effect as a return value that is not false? [This q&d fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/bf9sajkq/) seems to indicate that no return value is evaluated as false.

Comment: @MrLister: Yes, I am sure. A value being false (`value === false`) is not the same as a value that becomes false when converted to a boolean (`!value`). You can test the fiddle that I linked to in a comment above.